# How to make a table editable dynamically in google charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have created a table using DataTable in google charts. and also creating a pie chart using the table data.

I need to update/modify the table data dynamically on the browser and need to update the chart accordingly.

Please let me know how to make a table editable in the browser using google charts ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related Question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435268/google-chart-tables-edit-cells

Answer (score 1):

the data can be modified by using one of the available [methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods)

such as `setValue`
`data.setValue(rowIndex, columnIndex, newValue);`

anytime the `data` is changed, the `chart` must be re-drawn

see following working snippet, after the initial draw,
the data values are doubled and drawn again...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours'],
      ['A', 2],
      ['B', 4],
      ['C', 6],
      ['D', 8],
      ['E', 10],
      ['F', 12],
      ['G', 14]
    ]);

    var options = {
      height: 400,
      chartArea: {
        top: 24
      },
      legend: 'top',
      pieHole: 0.4,
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      width: 400
    };

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      // edit data
      for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        // double values
        data.setValue(i, 1, data.getValue(i, 1) * 2);
      }
      chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @WhiteHat.
You are hard coding the DataTable records here. But I need to take the values dynamically.

Comment: just an example, not sure i follow the question